# Is there any way to trigger an AWS lambda function with a Tweet from a specific User

Tags: amazon-web-services, twitter, aws-lambda, zapier

Just wondering if I am able to trigger a lambda function with a tweet from a specific user.

My plan is to use the lambda function to send out a pinpoint notification about the tweet that triggered the function.

I'm aware that you are able to link the two via Zapier but you require a premium membership, so was wondering if there is a free method or cheaper.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-twitter-event-source) tutorial from AwsLabs works great.

This will create a a lambda and a cloudwatch event rule to schedule it.
Creates a DynamoDb table to keep track of last processed event/timestamp.

We can pass in a filter like [Sachin Tendulkar-filter:retweets since:2021-01-01](https://twitter.com/search?q=Sachin%20Tendulkar-filter%3Aretweets%20since%3A2020-06-01&src=typed_query) to Cloudformation template when creating resources, it will use twitter api to pull the necessary tweets.

We need a twitter developer account for this. instructions are in [ReadMe](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-twitter-event-source/blob/master/README.md).

**Note:** This is we polling for tweets.

Comment: Thank you! I'll look it through and see if it can help me!